# error in the bigquery api explorer

Tags: google-bigquery

Using the api explorer I am getting this error. Note that using the Excel connector with same project and query works.  I did specify the scope as readonly.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "accessDenied",
    "message": "Access Denied: Job shufflepoint-project:job_5c8ec6808a89439eb4ac87943dbc6390: RUN_QUERY_JOB"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Denied: Job shufflepoint-project:job_5c8ec6808a89439eb4ac87943dbc6390: RUN_QUERY_JOB"
 }
```

Comment: Update: I reauthorized oauth using both the
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"
and
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly"
scopes. After doing so, Execute returned the expected JSON results.

Shouldn't queries work with the readonly scope?

Comment: Another update: Trying the same operation in my own code, I am getting "unsupported content with type: text/json"

Comment: answering my own question: changed content-type to "application/json" fixed that. Now am still curious about scope(s) needed to query.

Answer (score 0):

Running a query requires the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery scope. Given that query results can create tables, a query isn't really a read-only operation. We could enforce this for just queries where no table name is specified. Let me know if you would find this a valuable feature.